# Creating installer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msdeploy

I am experiencing problems creating facilities winforms applications in Visual Studio 2013.

On some computers (Windows 8), the deploy reports that:. "It is not possible to install or run this application The application requires a set of modules (assembly) Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers Version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the GAC ... "

How do I handle this problem?﻿

Answer (score 1):

If you set the 'CopyLocal' property of the reference file to 'true', it should copy the .dll into the output path of the project, and include it when you deploy.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Still the error appears. Even so, thanks.

Comment: can you look in the bin folder to see if the dll did copy there?

Comment: another thing you can try is create a 'Lib' folder in your project, and copy the .dll into there, then delete the reference to it and re-add it using the 'Browse' command instead of '.NET'.  Also, are all of the client machines 64 bit, or a mix of 32 and 64? What is your target framework set to?